# External monitor goes to sleep once vista loads?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, troubleshooting, display

My laptop's screen stopped working after a mishap with my dog, so I decided to turn it into a desktop computer.  I recently bought an HP w2207h monitor and will mirror the monitor image from the laptop screen onto this one.  This works fine with my CRT monitor, however I'm running into issues now.

When I boot the computer, the monitor is happy and I can see the Vista loading screen on it.  Once vista loads to the user login, the monitor says "Monitor going to sleep" and no image is displayed.  What gives?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem; I just open and close the laptop and everything works fine.

EDIT: it appears that, if you want to do anything "fancy" with the monitors later (add a second monitor, maybe), it's better to start with the lid up and THEN close the lid once you are logged in. (I saw it somewhere in the Windows Vista help, but I am not able to find the article at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

The laptop display is still listed in Vista as your primary monitor.  You may be able to switch this by pressing the function button and whatever key your laptop uses to switch monitors.